# Dropdown list postback related

Tags: asp.net

I want use "on item change event" in dropdown list  With auto post back enabled. But don't want to refresh whole page because I only want to change some other values in page  "on items changed". But whole page get refreshing and if I don't use auto post back then required task not completing. Any solution? Asp.Net + c# using visual studio.

Comment: Please post your relevant codes....

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Let's close this question as overly broad and counter-productive for SO. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get some work done in code-behind and avoid a full page refresh, you could put your DropDownList in an UpdatePanel. The other items that you want to update must also be in an UpdatePanel (the same, or another one, or several other ones).